# x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwpcap

Tags: cygwin, libpcap, winpcap

The problem message is the following:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libwpcap.a when searching for -lwpcap
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwpcap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already researched similar problems with this. I can assume that this is 64bit/32bit compatible problem or need to install libpcap-dev or etc.
Could you please tell me more exact solution(link or code) specifically about lwpcap's problem on Cygwin64.

My system environment is CYGWIN_NT-10.0 DESKTOP-DB9DM81 2.2.1(0.289/5/3) 2015-08-20 11:42 x86_64 Cygwin on windows10.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"libpcap-dev" sounds like a Linux package, but this is Windows.  You need to install the WinPcap developer's pack; see, for example, these "[WinPcap for Cygwin](https://rohc-lib.org/support/wiki/doku.php?id=winpcap)" instructions.